# PhpStorm not uploading after git checkout

Tags: git, ftp, phpstorm

The title pretty much sums it up.

In NetBeans, if I checked out a file or a whole new branch, the IDE would automatically upload the changed files to my FTP server.

PhpStorm does not do this, even with `Upload external changes` checked.
I have to manually upload the files (and remember which ones were changed).

My FTP is set up correctly and works when I upload manually from PhpStorm.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Not yet implemented: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2171 . In any case -- please try "File | Synchronize" after VCS checkout -- may help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to clone the repository on your FTP server and after each commit (or commits) you run a `git fetch/pull` on your FTP server.

You can automate if with a job or a service on your server instead of doing it manually.